# How to elegantly debug nan/inf on gradients in a Tensorflow model with RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Occassionally we may encounter some nan/inf in gradients during backprop on seq2seq Tensorflow models. How could we easily find the cause of such issue, e.g. by locating the op and time step on which nan/inf is produced?

Since the error occurs on backpropagation, we could not simply observe the gradient values with tf.Print(). Also in a RNN model, tf.add_check_numerics_ops() doesn't work, and we could not use tf.check_numerics() unless we dig into the messy tf libraries or reimplement the control flow manually. While tfdbg, as a general solution, is hard to use and extremely slow on large models.